# Create basic GB region postcode area map

Tags: qgis, united-kingdom, postal-code

I want to make a simple map of SW England that shows polygons over the postcode areas (e.g. EX1, PL19, each in an shaded area with boundary line). If I search the postcode area on Google Maps (online) it shows exactly the kind of area highlight I want on this map, only I want multiple ones on a single map.

My data is number of respondents per postcode area. I am happy to manually label each polygon with a number to show the respondents in that area, as I don't have that many areas. Or can create a CSV file with postcodes listed so they can be counted and displayed automatically (if such a thing is possible and worth the effort).

So far I have managed to bring up a basic ordnance survey map. I downloaded what I thought was the right postcode area shapefile but it is too broad - It shades the whole of e.g. EX rather than just EX1, EX2 etc. as separate areas.

Comment: One of the answers in the question (of which yours is a duplicate of) provides a link to [Open Door Logistics](http://www.opendoorlogistics.com/downloads/) which contains shapefiles broken down in postcode areas (e.g. EX1 1, EX14 2 etc).